# ubuntu 14.04 refuses to install alongside windows

Tags: system-installation

Trying to install dual boot windows 7 and Ubuntu 14.04. I've followed all  the instructions but Ubuntu 14.04 will not see any other partitions, not even the ext3 partition that i created in advance for it. this is on a Lenovo T520
with a 240G SSD.I've been dual booting Ubuntu with windows over 10 years now and have never encountered a Ubuntu build that would not recognize windows or any other partition on install.Please advise.  TIA, Wally

Comment: Boot from a bootable Ubuntu USB or DVD and select **Try Ubuntu**. After you're logged into Ubuntu, launch **Gparted** and see your SSD partitions.